# Is it possible to get custom profile attributes using Okta API?

Tags: api, okta, okta-api

I would like to get the complete profile attributes including base and custom using the Okta API. I need to use only the API which I can include using RestClient in my rails application. I tried to invoke Authentication as well as the various User API but only getting four or five parameters in return. Do we need to do any settings in the Account to get all the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same situation. Its really strange, but it seems OKTA works little differently.

OKTA Supports getUnmapped() method in its Java SDK to give all the unmapped attributes. However not in other languages. Hope OKTA will create or modify their existing APIs to overcome this.

In my case, the custom attribute was created properly in OKTA portal. And the value for the custom attribute was set on the user in OKTA user profile page. However still couldn't get the custom attribute value pair in the GET API response. Later I realized that after calling the create user API with the new custom attribute explicitly and then calling GET API gave me the attribute in the response.

Another way can be to set the custom attribute's value via update POST API and then calling GET will also start giving the custom attribute in the response.
Bear in mind that while calling update use POST method, if you use PUT, then you will have to provide all attributes and their values in the API input body otherwise the attributes not provided will be wiped out for the user.

Hope it helps. The use case at my end was solved by doing this.